# iOS app rejected for in app purchase "bug" - can't duplicate

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

I have submitted an app update for review and it has been rejected.  The reason stated for the rejection is:

> We found that your app exhibited one or more bugs, when reviewed on iPad running iOS 6.1, on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> After attempting to purchase additional content in your app, the user is presented with an alert stating that the app cannot connect to the iTunes Store. The user cannot continue with the purchase of additional content.

When I test with exactly the same binary that was submitted everything works fine.  I suspected that the reviewer was using a regular account in the sandbox environment or a test account in the live environment, which would exhibit the behavior described, so I resubmitted.

Now I've been rejected again with the same reason.  I have no idea what is going on - anyone ever seen anything like this?

Comment: Are you using receipt verification? I had similar problem and ended up removing the verification to get it through. Not sure what the problem was, maybe them not using the live servers. I added it later and it went through.

Comment: Hi Darren - no, I am not using receipt verification.  I'm planning to appeal in order to get more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All's well that ends well.  It appears that this was the result of reviewer error.  Upon further review the app has been approved for sale.

If anybody else has this problem, I would suggest filing an appeal.